# Dependency in POM looks dimmed in Maven Dependency folder and can't be imported, how to fix?

Tags: eclipse, maven

Tried to import a class in Eclipse IDE after configuring it in the POM.XML file, and I can't import in class.

[image]

It looks differentiated, his icon is darker than the others

[image]

Import writing seems okay, but it gives me error 'The import io cannot be resolved':

[image]

[image]

Comment: The darker icon means test scope. Does adding `<scope>compile</scope>` to that dependency help?

Comment: Did the changes in the pom, nothing changed.

Comment: Your Eclipse looks outdated. Please make sure your Eclipse is up to date. If that doesn't help, show a minimal `pom.xml` file (as text, not as an image) that can be used to reproduce your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example